# python writefile ImportError: No module named "mainss_script"

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror, writefile

```
%%writefile mainss_script.py
def count_vowels(sentence):
    """Count the number of vowels in sentence."""
    vowels = 0
    for c in sentence:
        if c.lower() in "aeiouy":
            vowels = vowels + 1
    return vowels

def count_consonants(sentence):
    """Count the number of consonants in sentence."""
    consonants = 0
    for c in sentence:
        if c.isalpha():
            if c.lower() not in "aeiouy":
                consonants = consonants + 1
    return consonants

def count_digits(sentence):
    """Count the number of digits in sentence."""
    digits = 0
    for c in sentence:
        if c.isdigit():
            digits = digits + 1
    return digits
def mainss():
    test_sentence = "Plan 2 is not working!"
    print("Number of vowels = {:d}".format(count_vowels(test_sentence)))
    print("Number of consonants = {:d}".format(count_consonants(test_sentence)))
    print("Number of digits = {:d}".format(count_digits(test_sentence)))

if (__name__=="__main__"):
    mainss()
```

---

```
import mainss_script
mainss_script.mainss()
```

---

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-1fd7edecdd49> in <module>()
----> 1 import mainss_script
      2 mainss_script.mainss()

ImportError: No module named 'mainss_script'
```

the mainss_script.py was generated, however, when I tried to import it, it returns error, why??

ignore for word requirement ignore for word requirement ignore for word requirement

Comment: @VineethSai %%writefile filename is a Jupyter notebook magic alias for writing contents of a cell to a file. In this case, the first block of code gets written to **mainss_script.py** when the cell containing those code was run. She is having trouble importing the file because the file does not exist or is not in a place known to the interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

The file **mainss_script.py** has to be in the directory where you launch ipython.

If not, you can insert its location into `sys.path` for the interpreter to find it

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "path to mainss_script.py")

import mainss_script
mainss_script.mainss()
```

Also, `%%writefile` is the Jupyter magic alias command to write the content of the cell to file. So my guess is your code was copied over from some Jupyter notebook and running the cell containing those lines creates `mainss_script` in the current directory.

If you don't have that file, paste those lines of code **excluding** the line containing `%%writefile` into a file **mainss_script.py** in the same directory where you launch IPython.

If for some reason you do wish to save **mainss_script.py** at a specific location, then you should follow the instructions above to add the path to **mainss_script** into `sys.path` for the interpreter to find it. After that  execute the lines to import and run `mainss()` and things should work.

Comment: I think it is in the same directory as when I use os.getcwd(), it returns the folder where mianss_script.py is saved. Also, when I run the file directly with %%bash, it works. somehow the import just doesnt.

Comment: Is the line `%%writefile mianss_script.py` at the top of mianss_script.py? If so, remove it.

Comment: @KarenJiang Also did you `cd` into your current directory after starting IPython? The code works for me. No problem with import and all that as long as the file is at the correct place.

Comment: I removed it and didnt cd back after.

Comment: I add the line：import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/nbuser/library/command_line/mainss_script.py")

import mainss_script
mainss_script.mainss()

Comment: by the way, I am using microsoft's azure

Comment: @KarenJiang Add the path to the **directory**, **not** the file. So the code should be `import sys; sys.path.insert(0, "/home/nbuser/library/command_line")`

Comment: @KarenJiang At this rate it is probably easiest if you quit ipython, then launch it in the directory containing the file. Then you won't have to bother with manually inserting the path into sys.path.